# how to prevent spam block attacks in cpp ethereum?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

it is really annoying. I'm running a sync with eth and every 1 or 3 hours there come giant spam block attacks, which slow down syncing dramatically. I delete network.rlp, restart eth and everything is ok for 1 or 2 hours. Than the next spam block attacks occur. Is there anybody, who has an idea what to do against these attacks?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean about "spam blocks"? What are you seeing exactly? If you're syncing the block data then... it's just the block data, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is blockdata, but must be partly malicious blockdata, because eth sometimes stops after those blocks logging the message 'abrupt peer disconnect'. Strange, that all these spamblocks occure only when i let run eth without --pin option.

Comment: forgot to mention when such a malicious block occur eth logs 'cannot Interpret data' and sometimes after that message comes the abrupt peer disconnect and eth is halted. After restarting eth everything is ok again until next occurence of a malicious block

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no way to prevent these attacks, but i can live with it